# Iterating through table eventually throws a Stale Element Exception

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a selenium C# script that iterates through a table and collects all the data in the rows. However after the third time I page down through the table, I receive a stale element exception. One thing to note is that this table is in an Iframe, and the data doesn't load unless you scroll down through the table. I got around this by collecting the TD and once I receive a blank TD, then page down to the next set of data in the table. How do I keep `tdCollection = row.FindElements(By.TagName"tr")` from going stale?

```
 do
    {
        IList<IWebElement> tdCollection;
        IWebElement table = driver.FindElement(By.Id("isc_Jtable"));
        var rows = table.FindElements(By.TagName("tr"));
        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            tdCollection = row.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
            if (tdCollection[0].Text == "")
            {
                CurrentFrame.ActiveElement().SendKeys(Keys.PageDown);
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.WriteLog(logName, String.Format("{1}{0}", " PCI ID: " + tdCollection[0].Text, DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime()));
                tdCount++;

            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `tdCollection = row.FindElements(By.TagName"tr")` is throwing `StaleElementReference` because it tries to access the `row` element which after couple of iterations has went stale, perhaps because the HTML elements `rows` represents have changed.

You should try to iterate dynamically through the table instead of getting a fixed list of rows which probably changes as you described.

```
IWebElement table = driver.FindElement(By.Id("isc_Jtable"));
int tableRowIndex = 1;
while (true) {
    try {
        var tableRow = table.FindElement(By.Xpath("tr[" + tableRowIndex + "]"));
        tableRowIndex++;
        IList<IWebElement> tdCollection = tableRow.FindElements(By.TagName("td"))
        // Do something with tdCollection
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
        // Last iteration
        break;
    }
}
```

You can see that I only keep a reference to the 'active' row and when I'm done processing its data, I'm finding the next one.

Also if you don't like the `while (true)` you can swap the `break` for a boolean flag which will be checked.